# Intercepting all outbound traffic on OSX

Tags: macos, cocoa

I want to intercept all outbound traffic on my Mac the same way Little Snitch does (just, in my code :)).

I can't seem to find any info on how to do this.
Are there any libraries I could use for Cocoa for this?
Perhaps some Unix library?

Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni your edit is not constructive, this question has nothing to do with the application little snitch.

Comment: OP says : I want to intercept all outbound traffic on my Mac **the same way Little Snitch does**. My interpretation is that it's a sufficient strong relation to add the little-snitch tag.

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni That tag isn't even on topic here.  And just because someone wants to emulate the behavior of the program does not mean that the tag is appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would check out libpcap (part of tcpdump): http://www.tcpdump.org/

Answer (score 4):

You could also use a kernel extension to implement a network socket filter. Developing a kext is more difficult but your program would not depend on the libpcap library.
Apple has a code sample at http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/tcplognke/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003669

Comment: Cheers, I'll investigate further :)

Comment: the above link is dead:https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KEXTConcept/KEXTConceptIntro/introduction.html